# Error al importar libreria en python desde php

Tags: php, python

Hola tengo un problema creo un archivo en python desde php y le agrego para importar la libreria zeep hago un print() sencillo pero al ejecutar no obtengo respuesta

coloco el codigo de muestra

```
$py="
from zeep import Client
print('prueba salida')
";
$temp_name='C:/xampp/htdocs/api/ResponsePy_'.uniqid().'.py';
file_put_contents($temp_name, utf8_encode($py));

$output = shell_exec('python '.$temp_name);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Debes instalar el modulo (`pip install zeep`) en el sistema para poder ejecutar el comando. Tienes permisos para ejecutar codigo en la linea de comandos?

Comment: la libreria ya esta instalada, ejecuto el archivo desde la consola y da resultado, de cuales permiso me habla? yo coloco solo el print() y si obtengo respuesta

Comment: Si esta la libreria instalada deberia funcionar, con permisos me referia a permiso para instalar el modulo. Agrega una linea al antes `ini_set('display_errors','on');` para ver que errores te entrega y agrega dichos mensajes en el post. Si lo pruebo localmente me funciona.